# Take one part of the string and swtich places with other

Tags: python-3.x

I have this

```
string = "Kabale (Blue/Purple 841, 34)"
```

and I want to switch what is inside braces places

so my desired result would be

```
string = "Kabale (34, Blue/Purple 841)"
```

how can i do it.

string can be diffirent like `"Vesta1 (Brown Stripes 227, 34)"` or

```
"Vincenta (Black 837, 34)"
```

but pattern is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this custom function

```py
def reverse_partition(string):
    first_parentheses = string.find('(')
    last_parentheses = string.find(')')
    target = string[first_parentheses+1:last_parentheses]
    target_split_by_comma = target.split(',')
    target_split_by_comma.reverse()
    return string.replace(target,', '.join(target_split_by_comma).strip())
```